# PouchDB put call getting 409: Document update conflict

Tags: backbone.js, pouchdb

stack:nodejs, backbone.js v1.3.3, underscore.js v1.8.3, JQuery v2.2.4, cordova v6.1.1, https://pouchdb.com/download.html v6.0.5, https://github.com/jo/backbone-pouch v?, https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

I've polled the todos-db for the record using the _id and updated the _rev attribute, but I can't find my way out of these conflicts, so all help appreciated:

In my TodoModel, I'm doing:

```
    return Backbone.Model.extend( {

        idAttribute:    "_id",
        db:         new PouchDB( "todos-db" ),
        sync:       this.BackbonePouch.sync( {
                    db: this.db,
                    fetch: "query",
                    options: {
                        query: {
                            include_docs: true
                        }
                    }
                } ),

        initialize:     function(){

                    this.listenTo( Backbone, "updateRec", function( model ){
                        this.updateRec( model );
                    } );
                },

        updateRec:  function( revRec ){

                    var self = this;
                    console.log( "revRec:", revRec );
                    this.db.get( revRec._id, { conflicts: true } ).then( function( doc ){
                        console.log( "doc:", doc ); // doc has no conflicts
                        revRec._rev = doc._rev;
                        return self.db.put( revRec );
                    } ).then( function( result ){
                        console.log( "updateRec result:", result ); 
                        return result;
                    } ).catch( function( err ){
                        // TODO: the above 'put' is throwing multiple confict errors, yet the db is updating after 7 tries
                        console.log( err ); 
                    } );

                }
    } );

});
```

In the log, revRec gives me:

```
_id:"2016-09-27T16:45:34.297Z"
_rev:"5-b554a2b4989efedac3ca3ccb679aa42e"
completed:false
delegatedTo:"Jen"
due:"Friday"
priority:"A"
project:"home"
task:"MBath concept"
```

The 'put' result gives me:

```
{ok: true, id: "2016-09-27T16:45:34.297Z", rev: "6-c6647848d965c35c7ac4f968cac7a91b"}
```

and the catch err is:

```
CustomPouchError {status: 409, name: "conflict", message: "Document update conflict", error: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [pouchdb-upsert](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert) or read about [conflicts](https://pouchdb.com/guides/conflicts.html).

In your code, I believe your particular error most likely stems from race conditions in requesting the same document multiple times (e.g. if the user clicks very quickly?). `pouchdb-upsert` would automatically handle such errors for you.